# Which of the mangas of Arifureta is the anime based on?

Tags: arifureta

As far as I know, there are 3 mangas of *Arifureta*.

- *Arifureta Shokugyō de Sekai*
- *Arifureta Shokugyō de Sekai Saikyō Zero*, and
- *Arifureta Nichijō de Sekai Saikyō*

Which one of them is the anime based on, and where do they fit in the animated series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, *both the anime and the manga are adapted from the light novels*.

[MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/88923/Arifureta_Shokugyou_de_Sekai_Saikyou) states that the anime is an adaptation of the light novel and all the manga aside from the spin-off are just an alternative version of the light novel. *Arifureta Nichijō de Sekai Saikyō* is just a [4-koma spin-off detailing their daily lives](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=144760) so I don't think it would impact the main timeline that much.

As for the order of events:

- *Arifureta Shokugyō de Sekai Saikyō Zero* (as far as I know, this was not adapted by the anime as it is a prequel to the events in *Arifureta Shokugyō de Sekai*)
- *Arifureta Shokugyō de Sekai* (the light novels of this are the ones adapted by the anime; the manga is just an alternative version)
- *Arifureta Nichijō de Sekai Saikyō* (daily life during *Arifureta Shokugyō de Sekai* events)